# Spring Error- BeanDefinitionParsingException

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I'm getting the following error since I added neo4j to my spring mvc project (add default packages like spring-context, spring-webmvc, etc).

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(…) is not public! Make sure you're using Spring 3.2.5 or better. The class was loaded from file:/Users/mariamdost/Downloads/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/CodeChallenge/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar.
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationConfigUtils.processCommonDefinitionAnnotations(…) is not public! Make sure you're using Spring 3.2.5 or better. The class was loaded from file:/Users/mariamdost/Downloads/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/CodeChallenge/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar.
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
```

As the error says I then deleted the default spring-context (3.1.1) and added again and it got rid of that error but then I ran into even more errors. The next error was that spring-expression and spring-context were of different versions so I fixed it by adding spring-expression and excluding spring-expression from neo4j. Then I ran into the final error:

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethod: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()
```

The last error I cannot find any solution. So reverted back to my initial state and I'm wondering is there another db I can use that will work with my current project setup? If not then how can I fix the current error I have? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your library dependencies, project setup and config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have added some incompatible spring jars. The [java.lang.NoSuchMethod](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) error suggests that the expected method is not found in the dependent class . You would need to have look at the classes that you have added and correct them.